# redshift drop table with + and spaces in name

Tags: redshift

I have a table that a user created which appears to be from a python variable that never interpolated.

```
proddb01=# \dt+ *transtable*
                    List of relations
 schema |      name       | type  | owner  | description
--------+-----------------+-------+--------+-------------
 public |  + transtable + | table | app |
(1 row)
```

I am unable to drop it, I can only describe it with the \dt+ and wildcard method.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should add that as an answer and accept that answer so that your question can be marked as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question, a co worker was able to see a space in front of the first plus sign. I was not seeing this, so quoted drop worked.

```
proddb01=#drop table " + transtable +"; 
DROP TABLE
```